# How can I loop an array from certain position in clockwise and counterclockwise?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

I have this array:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

To Loop in a Clockwise Direction ( Start 8, then 9, then 10, then 0.....) I'm doing this way:

```
var start = 8;
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    index = (start+i)%array.length;
    ....
}
```

**1) To Clockwise Direction, there's a better way?**

**2) To Loop in a CounterClockwise Direction (Start 2, then 1, then 0, then 10...), what should I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it similar to what you did, decrease the index from the starting index and add the length before trimming:

```
var start = 8;
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  index = (start - i + array.length) % array.length;
  // ....
}
```

Regarding "how to do it better", I'd create a simple helper function:

```
function getIndexInRange(index, length) {
  var trim = index % length;
  var nonNegative = trim + length;
  return nonNegative % length;
}
```

Then it all becomes clearer:

```
var start = 8;
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var index = getIndexInRange(start + i, array.length);
  // ....
}

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var index = getIndexInRange(start - i, array.length);
  // ....
}
```

Now you can even iterate the array multiple times if you want, and it still works:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length * 5; i++) {
  var index = getIndexInRange(start - i, array.length);
  // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very hepfull and clean.

Answer (score 1):

I created a jsbin here.

http://jsbin.com/tucusal/edit?html,js,console

You can even create a function that takes direction input and then traverses array in that direction.

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var start = 8;
clockwise = 1;
anti_clockwise = -1;

direction = clockwise;
traverse(array, start, anti_clockwise);

function traverse(array, start,  direction) {
  var count = array.length;
  for (i = start; count > 0; i += direction) {
    var index = array[(array.length + i) % array.length];
    count--;
    console.log(index);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];


function clockwise(start){
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        console.log((start+i)%array.length);
    }
}

function counterClockwise(start){
    for (var i = array.length; i > 0; i--){
        console.log((start+i)%array.length);
    }
}

console.log('clockwise start from ');
clockwise(8);
console.log('clockwise End  ');

console.log('counterClockwise start from ');
counterClockwise(2);
console.log('counterClockwise End  ');
```

Comment: Thanks, very hepfull and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a single function for both directions:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function iterateByClockRotation(start, array, direction){
    var len = array.length, current = start;
    while (len--) {
        current = array.indexOf(current);
        if (current < 0) current = ((direction === "clockwise")? 0 : array.length-1);
        console.log(array[current]); // the current value
        (direction === "clockwise")? current++ : current--;
    }
}

iterateByClockRotation(8, array, "clockwise");
```

The output for 'clockwise' direction:

```
8
9
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

---

```
iterateByClockRotation(2, array, "anticlockwise");
```

The output for 'anticlockwise' direction:

```
2
1
0
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Array.prototype.slice` to change start of array:

```js
Array.prototype.enhancedForEach = function(callback, start = 0, clockwise = true) {
  var array = this;
  start %= array.length;

  array.slice(start)
    .concat(array.slice(0, start))
    .forEach((v, i, arr) => {
      var index = clockwise ? i : arr.length - i - 1;
      callback(arr[index], index, arr);
    });

}

array = Array.from({
  length: 20
}, (v, i) => i);

array.enhancedForEach(v => console.log(v), 4);

array.enhancedForEach(v => console.log(v), 0, false);
```

```html
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37981887/edit#
```